# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users' --showing in django

Tags: python, django

My directory

```
MLG
 >.vscode
 >blog
 >users
 -db.sqlite3
 -manage.py
```

This is users views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/regsiter.html', {'form': form})
```

This is users apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'
```

This is mlg settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],

        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

This is  mlg urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views


urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),

]
```

What i am doing wrong please help...
P.S. - I have shown templates just as i am trying to run register.html file .. cant able to run it bcz of above error ..

Comment: in installed apps you have to add your app name only, if you have a app name say blog, just add blog

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog',
    'users',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
Like this?

Comment: inorder to see your templates add this  'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

Comment: Your setting seems to be good - do you have `__init__.py` file created in `users` dir? You need to have it. Please provide Some Output, BugTrace

Comment: yes i have that file in my users dir DawidGacek .. still not working bmons

Comment: How do you run it, and what it shows? I copied your code, and tried to run django - and it works. Also what django version do You use?

Comment: django 3 DawidGacek

Comment: from users import views as signup_views
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users'
         when i am running urls.py (mlg) DawidGacek